# TensorFlow: An alternative to tf.scatter_update

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two Tensors like this:

```
template = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3],                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                 [1, 0, 0.75, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3],                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                 [1, 0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.3, 0.3],                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                 [1, 0, 0.75, 0.75, 0.3, 0.3]])                                                                                                                                                                                                   

patch = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0, 1, 0.43, 0.17, 0.4, 0.4],                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                              [0, 1, 0.18, 0.22, 0.53, 0.6]])
```

Now I would like to update the second and the last rows of the `template` with the `patch` rows to get a value like this:

```
[[1.   0.   0.5  0.5  0.3  0.3 ]
 [0.   1.   0.43 0.17 0.4  0.4 ]
 [1.   0.   0.5  0.75 0.3  0.3 ]
 [0.   1.   0.18 0.22 0.53 0.6 ]]
```

With `tf.scatter_update` it is easy:

```
var_template = tf.Variable(template)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
var_template = tf.scatter_update(var_template, [1, 3], patch)
```

However, it requires creating a variable. Is there a way to obtain the value using only tensor operations?

I was thinking about `tf.where`, but then I probably have to broadcast every patch row into the template size and call `tf.where` for each row.

Comment: And what is a problem with creating a variable?

Comment: That would be my second question :) This code is part of pre-processing chain for a model. I want it to be stateless. I think variables have different purpose: to store weights, states etc.

Comment: I think this reply by mrry describes the difference quite well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866675/implementation-difference-between-tensorflow-variable-and-tensorflow-tensor

I would not be afraid to use `tf.Variable` in pre-processing. I used it for example for image augmentation with the `tf.scatter_nd_update` in the `map()` part of Dataset API. Just remember to use `tf.get_variable` not the `tf.Variable` itself.

Comment: I am a bit worry about the locking of Variables during update. I am afraid this may hurt performance for multi-GPU multi-machine setup.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with multi-GPU or multi-machine setups.

Comment: Anyway, did my answer answer your question? ;)
If so, could you please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should work. A bit twisted, but no variable used.

```
import tensorflow as tf
template = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3],                                                                       
                                 [2, 2, 0.75, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3],                                                                      
                                 [3, 3, 0.5, 0.75, 0.3, 0.3],                                                                      
                                 [4, 4, 0.75, 0.75, 0.3, 0.3]])   

patch = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1, 1, 1, 0.17, 0.4, 0.4],                                                                           
                              [3, 3, 3, 0.22, 0.53, 0.6]])

ind = tf.constant([1,3])
rn_t = tf.range(0, template.shape[0])

def index1d(t, val):
    return tf.reduce_min(tf.where(tf.equal([t], val)))

def index1dd(t,val):
    return tf.argmax(tf.cast(tf.equal(t,val), tf.int64), axis=0)

r = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.where(tf.equal(index1d(ind, x), 0), patch[index1dd(ind, x)] , template[x]), rn_t, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run([r]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add here also my solution. This utility function works pretty much the same as `scatter_update`, but without using Variables:

```
def scatter_update_tensor(x, indices, updates):                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    '''                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    Utility function similar to `tf.scatter_update`, but performing on Tensor                                                                                                                                                                                         
    '''                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    x_shape = tf.shape(x)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    patch = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, x_shape)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    mask = tf.greater(tf.scatter_nd(indices, tf.ones_like(updates), x_shape), 0)                                                                                                                                                                                      
    return tf.where(mask, patch, x)
```