# What's the difference between Tensor and Variable in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

What's the difference between `Tensor` and `Variable` in Tensorflow? I noticed in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556078/in-tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-and-a-tensor), we can use `Variable` wherever `Tensor` can be used. However, I failed to do `session.run()` on a `Variable`:

```py
A = tf.zeros([10])   # A is a Tensor
B = tf.Variable([111, 11, 11]) # B is a Variable
sess.run(A) # OK. Will return the values in A
sess.run(B) # Error.
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) is basically a wrapper on [`Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) that maintains state across multiple calls to `run`, and I think makes some things easier with saving and restoring graphs. A `Variable` needs to be initialized before you can run it. You provide an initial value when you define the `Variable`, but you have to call its initializer function in order to actually assign this value in your session and then use the `Variable`. A common way to do this is with [`tf.global_variables_initalizer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer).

For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
test_var = tf.Variable([111, 11, 1])
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(test_var)

# Error!

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  # initialize variables
sess.run(test_var)
# array([111, 11, 1], dtype=int32)
```

As for why you use `Variable`s instead of `Tensor`s, basically a `Variable` is a `Tensor` with additional capability and utility. You can specify a `Variable` as trainable (the default, actually), meaning that your optimizer will adjust it in an effort to minimize your cost function; you can specify where the `Variable` resides on a distributed system; you can easily save and restore `Variable`s and graphs. Some more information on how to use `Variable`s can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables).

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot more sense. Indeed, I didn't initialize the variables.

Comment: To add more information: Normal `tf.Tensor` objects are immutable. To store model weights (or other mutable state) in TensorFlow use a `tf.Variable` (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/basics#variables)