# Keras Backend: Difference between random_normal and random_normal_variable

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

My neural network has a custom layer, which takes an input vector `x`, generates  a normally distributed tensor `A` and returns both `A` (used in subsequent layers) and the product `Ax`.  Assuming I want to reuse the value stored in `A` at the output of the custom layer, in a second different layer, is there any subtle aspect that I need to factor while determining which Keras backend function (`K.backend.random_normal` or `K.backend.random_normal_variable`) I should use in order to generate `A`?

a) The backend function `random_normal` returns a tensor storing a different value following each call (see code snippet below). To me, this suggests that `random_normal` acts as a generator of normally distributed values. Does this mean that one should not use `random_normal` to generate a normally distributed tensor if they want to hold its value following calls?

b) The backend function `random_normal_variable` appears safer (see code snippet below) as it retains value across calls.

Is my conceptual understanding correct? Or am I missing something basic?
I am using Keras 2.1.2 and Tensorflow 1.4.0.

Experiment with `random_normal` (value changes across calls):

```
In [5]: A = K.random_normal(shape = (2,2), mean=0.0, stddev=0.5) 
In [6]: K.get_value(A)
Out[6]: array([[ 0.4459489 , -0.82019573],
   [-0.39853573, -0.33919844]], dtype=float32)
In [7]: K.get_value(A)
Out[7]: array([[-0.37467018,  0.42445764],
   [-0.573843  , -0.3468301 ]], dtype=float32)
```

Experiment with `random_normal_variable` (value holds across calls):

```
In [9]: B = K.random_normal_variable(shape=(2,2), mean=0., scale=0.5)
In [10]: K.get_value(B)
Out[10]: array([[ 0.07700552,  0.28008622],
   [-0.69484973, -1.32078779]], dtype=float32)
In [11]: K.get_value(B)
Out[11]: array([[ 0.07700552,  0.28008622],
   [-0.69484973, -1.32078779]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, this is due to the fact that `random_normal_variable` returns an instantiated `Variable` while `random_normal` returns a `Tensor`.

```
K.random_normal(shape=(2,2), mean=0.0, stddev=0.5) 
<tf.Tensor 'random_normal:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32>

K.random_normal_variable(shape=(2,2), mean=0.0, scale=0.5)
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32_ref>
```

As for why the values vary for the `Tensor` and not for the `Variable`, I think the answer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167134/whats-the-difference-between-tensor-and-variable-in-tensorflow) sums it up well:

> `Variable` is basically a wrapper on `Tensor` that maintains state across multiple calls to run [...]

The answer also mentions that the variable needs to be initialized to evaluate it, which is the case here as you noticed (since you did not  initialize the variable to evaluate it). In fact, the returned variable is already initialized thanks to a call to `tensorflow.random_normal_initializer` within the `random_normal_variable` function. Hope this clarifies why your code has this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was thinking along similar lines and it is good to see that our understandings are similar.