# Tensorflow 2 - tf.slice and its NumPy slice syntax incompatible behavior

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, slice, tensorflow2.0

## Question

Please confirm if the below is as designed and expected, or an issue of [tf. slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice), or a mistake in the usage of `tf. slice`. If a mistake, kindly suggest how to correct it.

## Background

[Introduction to tensor slicing - Extract tensor slices](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor_slicing#extract_tensor_slices) says Numpy-like slice syntax is an alternative of `tf. slice`.

> Perform NumPy-like tensor slicing using tf. slice.
>
> ```
> t1 = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
> print(tf.slice(t1,
>                begin=[1],
>                size=[3]))
> ```
>
> **Alternatively, you can use a more Pythonic syntax**. Note that tensor slices are evenly spaced over a start-stop range.
>
> ```
> print(t1[1:4])
> ```

## Problem

To Update the dark orange region.

```
TYPE = tf.int32
N = 4
D = 5
shape = (N,D)

# Target to update
Y = tf.Variable(
    initial_value=tf.reshape(tf.range(N*D,dtype=TYPE), shape=shape),
    trainable=True
)
print(f"Target Y: \n{Y}\n")
---
Target Y: 
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(4, 5) dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]], dtype=int32)>
```

[image]

`tf. slice` does not work.

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Slice region in the target to be updated
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S = tf.slice(      # Error "EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'assign'"
    Y,
    begin=[0,1],   # Coordinate (n,d) as the start point
    size=[3,2]     # Shape (3,2) -> (n+3, n+2) as the end point
)
print(f"Slice to update S: \n{S}\n")

# Values to set
V = tf.ones(shape=tf.shape(S), dtype=TYPE)
print(f"Values to set V: \n{V}\n")

# Assing V to S region of T
S.assign(V)
---
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e5692b1750c8> in <module>
     24 
     25 # Assing V to S region of T
---> 26 S.assign(V)

AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

However, **slice syntax** works.

```
S = Y[
    0:3,           # From coordinate (n=0,d),   slice rows (0,1,2)  or 'size'=3 -> shape (3,?)
    1:3            # From coordinate (n=0,d=1), slice columns (1,2) or 'size'=2 -> shape (3,2)
]                  
print(f"Slice to update S: \n{S}\n")

# Values to set
V = tf.ones(shape=tf.shape(S), dtype=TYPE)
print(f"Values to set V: \n{V}\n")

# Assing V to S region of T
S.assign(V)
---
<tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=(4, 5) dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 0,  1,  1,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  1,  1,  8,  9],
       [10,  1,  1, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]], dtype=int32)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, the above behavior **is expected** or **not a bug** at least. As the error said, **there is no** attribute called [`assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign) in [`tf. Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) (`EagerTensor` for eager execution) but **there is in** [`tf. Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable). And generally, [`tf. slice`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py#L1051-L1103) returns **a tensor** as its output and thus it doesn't possess [`assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign) attribute.

```
AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

But when we do `np` like slicing and use it to modify the original `tf. Variable`, it seamlessly works.

---

## Possible Solution

A workaround is to use [`tf.strided_slice`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py#L1107-L1247) instead of [`tf.slice`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py#L1051-L1103). If we follow the source code of it, we will see, it takes the `var` argument which is a variable corresponding to `input_`

```
@tf_export("strided_slice")
@dispatch.add_dispatch_support
def strided_slice(input_,
                  begin,
                  end,
                  ..........
                  var=None,
                  name=None):
```

And when we pass a parameter for `var` that basically corresponding to the `input_`, it then calls [`assign` function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py#L1225-L1247) that is defined within it

```
def assign(val, name=None):
      """Closure that holds all the arguments to create an assignment."""

      if var is None:
        raise ValueError("Sliced assignment is only supported for variables")
      else:
        if name is None:
          name = parent_name + "_assign"

        return var._strided_slice_assign(
            begin=begin,
            end=end,
            strides=strides,
            value=val,
            name=name,
            begin_mask=begin_mask,
            end_mask=end_mask,
            ellipsis_mask=ellipsis_mask,
            new_axis_mask=new_axis_mask,
            shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)
```

So, when we pass `var` in the `tf.strided_slice`, it will return an assignable object.

---

## Code

Here is the full working code for reference.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
print(tf.__version__)

TYPE = tf.int32
N = 4
D = 5
shape = (N,D)

# Target to update
Y = tf.Variable(
    initial_value=tf.reshape(tf.range(N*D,dtype=TYPE), shape=shape),
    trainable=True
)
Y

2.4.1
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(4, 5) dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]], dtype=int32)>
```

Now, we use `tf.stried_slice` instead of `tf.slice`.

```
S = tf.strided_slice(
    Y, 
    begin = [0, 1],
    end   = [3, 3],
    var   = Y,
    name  ='slice_op'
)
S

<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 6,  7],
       [11, 12]], dtype=int32)>
```

Update the variables with no attribution error.

```
# Values to set
V = tf.ones(shape=tf.shape(S), dtype=TYPE)
print(V)
print()

# Assing V to S region of T
S.assign(V)

tf.Tensor(
[[1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32)

<tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=(4, 5) dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 0,  1,  1,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  1,  1,  8,  9],
       [10,  1,  1, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]], dtype=int32)>
```

Using `np` like slicing.

```
# slicing 
S = Y[
    0:3,           
    1:3            
]                  
S
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 6,  7],
       [11, 12]], dtype=int32)>

# Values to set
V = tf.ones(shape=tf.shape(S), dtype=TYPE)
print(V)
# Assing V to S region of T
S.assign(V)
tf.Tensor(
[[1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32)
<tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=(4, 5) dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 0,  1,  1,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  1,  1,  8,  9],
       [10,  1,  1, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]], dtype=int32)>
```

---

**Materials**

- [tf.Variable - tf.Tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44167844/9215780).